# PHP join three tables when if the data is not in one of them

Tags: php, email, tracker

I am working on joining three tables together, but in one of the tables no information will be in there, unless the user opens the email we sent them

I am currently using this sql but it seems not to work correctly

```
SELECT email.senton, customer.*, count(tracker.viewed) as viewed 
FROM email_sent AS email, customer_detail AS customer, email_tracker AS tracker 
WHERE email.customer_id = customer.customer_id 
    AND customer.Email = tracker.emailaddress 
    AND customer.LeadOwnerId = '{$this->userid}'
```

This is due to the table email_tracker may not have the customers info in it, unless the customer has opened the email

Comment: Just as a suggestion: Format the query so it's easier to read and you make it easier for others to help you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT email.senton, customer.*, COUNT(tracker.viewed) as viewed 
FROM email_sent email INNER JOIN customer_detail customer
    ON email.customer_id = customer.customer_id
LEFT JOIN email_tracker tracker 
    ON customer.Email = tracker.emailaddress
WHERE customer.LeadOwnerId = '{$this->userid}'
```

The **LEFT JOIN** clause is used to always get columns on the left part and columns on the right part if they exist in the join...

**EDITED according to your comment:**
Try to change `COUNT(tracker.viewed)` part with

```
CASE
    WHEN tracker.emailaddress IS NOT NULL THEN COUNT(tracker.viewed)
    ELSE 0
END
    as viewed
```

I'm not sure it works, I cannot test it, but give it a try

Comment: That works but the count(tracker.viewed) seems to stop the left join working. Is there any other way to do the count part

Comment: I found I had to do a group function to group by customer_id then all worked.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior that you want is the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (also known as `LEFT JOIN`). It just set's the value to `NULL` if the row doesn't exist in the other table.

```
SELECT email.senton, customer.*, COUNT(tracker.viewed) AS viewed
FROM email_sent AS email
    JOIN customer_detail AS customer USING(customer_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN email_tracker AS tracker ON customer.Email = tracker.emailaddress
WHERE customer.LeadOwnerId = '{$this->userid}'
```

PS: It's generally a better idea to use [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)s instead of a Cartesian product (what you did with `,`).

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use `JOIN` instead of Cartesian product, it makes queries much easier to read and modify. I'm confused about the "`left outer join` (..) *also known as (..) `outer join`*" part. Is it valid in some DBMS to write just "*<source> outer join <another source> on ...*"? MySQL does not allow this, not sure about others. And would it really be the same as "*left outer join*" (returns one row for every row that exists in left table) rather than "*both left outer and right outer*" (returns one row for every row that exists in either left or right table)?

Comment: @binaryLV That was just me remembering wrong. I though that mysql allows you to write just outer join and left is implied, but it doesn't seem so ^^ I edited the answer